# Convergence time of Q-learning Vs Deep Q-learning

Tags: deep-learning, q-learning, dqn

I want to know about the convergence time of Deep Q-learning vs Q-learning when run on same problem. Can anyone give me an idea about the pattern between them? It will be better if it is explained with a graph.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the more complicated the state is, the better DQN is over Q-Learning (by complicated, I mean the number of all possible states). When the state is too complicated, Q-learning becomes nearly impossible to converge due to time and hardware limitation.

---

note that DQN is in fact a kind of Q-Learning, it uses a neural network to act like a q table, both Q-network and Q-table are used to output a Q value with the state as input. I will continue using Q-learning to refer the simple version with Q-table, DQN with the neural network version

You can't tell convergence time without specifying a specific problem, because it really depends on what you are doing:

For example, if you are doing a simple environment like FrozenLake:https://gym.openai.com/envs/FrozenLake-v0/ 
Q-learning will converge faster than DQN as long as you have a reasonable reward function.
This is because FrozenLake has only 16 states, Q-Learning's algorithm is just very simple and efficient, so it runs a lot faster than training a neural network.

However, if you are doing something like atari:https://gym.openai.com/envs/Assault-v0/ 
there are millions of states (note that even a single pixel difference is considered totally new state), Q-Learning requires enumerating all states in Q-table to actually converge (so it will probably require a very large memory plus a very long training time to be able to enumerate and explore all possible states). In fact, I am not sure if it is ever going to converge in some more complicated game, simply because of so many states.

Here is when DQN becomes useful. Neural networks can generalize the states and find a function between state and action (or more precisely state and Q-value). It no longer needs to enumerate, it instead learns information implied in states. Even if you have never explored a certain state in training, as long as your neural network has been trained to learn the relationship on other similar states, it can still generalize and output the Q-value. And therefore it is a lot easier to converge.

Comment: What if it is a weather prediction problem with 24 states that are repeating?  Each state is constructed with the hour of the day and the weather info to 12 recent time slot. It is not like the fixed environment like frozen lake. It is a continuous process.  Will DQN work better?

Comment: @A_Tahsin for time series (weather for example) prediction, DQN works much better (I don't even think Q-Learning will work at all). **HOWEVER**, Reinforcement learning, in general, is NOT a good choice here, you might want to try deep learning instead. Reinforcement Learning is meant to mimic how humans learn to do something: choose actions to maximize rewards in environments, and get feedback from environments, it is common to use RL for something like video games, robotics. Prediction is a regression problem, so Deep Learning (especially RNN) or traditional Machine learning would be better.

Comment: There are problems for which standard Q-learning just isn't feasible. The game of Go for example has approximately 10^172 states. To put that into perspective, there's estimated to be approximately 10^80 atoms in the observable universe. For such a problem we have no choice but to use a function approximator such as a deep neural network.